# SSDT BI Custom Connection Manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I'm attempting to create a custom connection manager for use in SSDT BI jobs but I'm having an issue getting the custom connection manager to show up as an option.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the SSDT BI plugin (or whatever they call it) for creating everything.

I've created a new class which implements ConnectionMangerBase and I've applied the correct DtsConnection attribute to the class. I'm using the following "Post Build" commands to deploy the .dll. The connection manager uses the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. Google only revealed one site with info on where to put these dlls (the last to lines of the post build).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" -u $(TargetName)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" -iF $(TargetFileName)
copy $(TargetFileName) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Connections\$(TargetFileName)" /y

copy "$(TargetDir)Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies" /y
copy "$(TargetDir)Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn" /y
```

I've confirmed that my dll has been successfully deployed to the GAC and copied to, what I think are, the correct locations. However, when I create a new SSDT BI project, and try to create a new connection, my connection manager does not show up as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the SqlServer SDK was corrupt or missing something. I re-installed the SDK components and now everything is working fine.